# Drupal 7 jQuery issue with Contextual links, LightBox 2, Bootstrap components Carousel & Tabs

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, lightbox2

I created my custom theme with Bootstrap 3 for my CMS Drupal.

**1. example:**
In .info file for my custom theme I included js files:
scripts[] = js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
scripts[] = js/bootstrap.min.js

**Result:**
My Bootstrap components are working, also Lightbox 2 is working, but overlay is not working properly. Via contextual links if I click for edit for example block content I got empty overlay without content for edit block.

**Error in chrome developer tools:**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined (anonymous function)

**2. example:** with lower v. 1 of jQuery
In .info file for my sutom theme I included js files:
scripts[] = js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
scripts[] = js/bootstrap.min.js

**Result:**
Same as before.

**3. example:**
I tried only include bootstrap file and install module "jQuery Update" to avoid this problem: 
scripts[] = js/bootstrap.min.js

**Result:**
My "Carousel & Tabs" are working also "Contextual Links" but Lightbox 2 in my photo gallery is showing empty window without image :(

Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined admin_menu.js?nbxxex:223Drupal.admin.behaviors.hover admin_menu.js?nbxxex:223(anonymous function) admin_menu.js?nbxxex:165x.extend.each jquery-1.10.2.js:665Drupal.admin.attachBehaviors admin_menu.js?nbxxex:164(anonymous function) admin_menu.js?nbxxex:42c jquery-1.10.2.js:3048p.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160k jquery-1.10.2.js:8235r

I tried:
1. include jquery-1.10.2.js
2. uninstall "Administration menu" module.
3. in advanced settings for Lightbox 2 set footer javascript include instead head.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found solution one solution for this.

1. in .info file you can't add any jquery:
   <strike>scripts[] = js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</strike>
2. install module jQuery Update
3. in configuration of jQuery Update set:

   - Default jQuery Version -> choose: 1.9
   - Alternate jQuery version for administrative pages -> 1.8
4. use instead of Lightbox 2 -> Colorbox.

This solved my issue now I'm able to go to sections via contextual links, my bootstrap components are working and also colorbox is working in my photo gallery is working as well ;)

Unfortunetlly my Lightbox 2 is not working for these settings.
I tried all my best but withou success.

My settings are:

WampServer 2.5 - but I also tried it on linux server from my host provider

PHP: 5.5.12

APACHE: 2.4.9

MySQL: 5.6.17

Bootstrap 3.2

jQuery 2.1.1 not working so it's 1.9.1 which I'm using

Colorbox: 7.x-2.8

Colorbox plugin: 1.5.14

Lightbox 2: 7.x-1.0-beta1 or 7.x-1.x-dev not working

Drupal: 7.31

Also you can test you jQuery in page.tpl.php for example with this code:

```
<script>
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
</script>
```